# Is it possible go online for a multiplayer match on Quake (1996)

Tags: quake

Quake was once known for its LAN parties but since LAN is (for the most part) is dead. The servers never seem to work when I try go on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [the new remaster](https://store.steampowered.com/app/2310/QUAKE/) there has been a surge in popularity. I'm not sure if the new servers are compatible with the original Quake, but if you had it on Steam you got the upgrade for free.

I don't know where to get good multiplayer stats, but currently 1.0% of players have the "in deathmatch, electrocute an enemy in water without dying" achievement, compared to 31.2% who have the "find a secret area" achievement. Note that these numbers are skewed down because the total includes everyone who played before the achievements were added.

All the servers are working though, so if you can get some friends together there should be no problem. You also get 4-player local multiplayer (including via Remote Play Together) so you don't even need to rely on servers.